# reordering script goes wrong unexpectedly

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I wrote a function in plain javascript to reorder a list, I tried to convert it to react, I entered the values 1 acting as 'n' and 2 acting as 'to', but when I console log updatedJson, which is a shallow copy, it gives me a completely distorted dictionary, just after the line 'After splice' is logged. Why does this happen when in plain javascript it's completely fine?

Distorted dictionary

```
0
: 
{type: 'sleep', seconds: '6'}
1
: 
{type: 'sleep', seconds: '6'}
2
: 
{type: 'sleep', seconds: '30'}
```

Plain javascript working function

```
window.json = [{'type':'sleep', 'seconds': '15'},
                    {'type':'sleep', 'seconds': '30'},
                    {'type':'sleep', 'seconds': '6'}]

function reorder(n,to){     
    item = window.json[n];     
    window.json.splice(n,1)     
    if(n>to){        
        for(i=n;i--;i>to){             
            window.json[i+1] = window.json[i]         
        }         
    window.json[to] = item;    
     }          
    if(n<to){         
        for(i=n;i++;i<to){             
            window.json[i-1] = window.json[i]         
        }         
    window.json[to] = item;     
    } }
```

Bugged out script

```
//WindowJson = [{'type':'sleep', 'seconds': '15'},{'type':'sleep', 'seconds': '30'},{'type':'sleep', 'seconds': '6'}]

function ReorderAction(n,to){
        console.log('Affected item')
        console.log(WindowJson[n])
        console.log('Default WindowJson')
        console.log(WindowJson)
        console.log('Default Updated')
        const updatedJson = [...WindowJson];
        console.log(updatedJson)

        var item = updatedJson[n];
        updatedJson.splice(n,1);
        console.log('After Splice')
        console.log(updatedJson)
        if(n>to){
            for(let i=n;i>to;i--){
                updatedJson[i+1] = updatedJson[i];
                console.log('In loop')
                console.log(updatedJson)
            }
            updatedJson[to] = item;
        }
        if(n<to){
            for(let i=n;i<to;i++){
                updatedJson[i-1] = updatedJson[i];
                console.log('In loop')
                console.log(updatedJson)
            }
            updatedJson[to] = item; 
        }
        console.log('End result')
        console.log(updatedJson)
        setWindowJson(updatedJson);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have a problem with your references and here is how you should edit it:

```
function ReorderAction(n, to) {
    console.log('Affected item');
    console.log(WindowJson);
    console.log('Default WindowJson');
    console.log(WindowJson);
    console.log('Default Updated');
    const updatedJson = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(WindowJson));
    console.log(updatedJson);

    var item = updatedJson[n];
    updatedJson.splice(n, 1);
    console.log('After Splice');
    console.log(updatedJson);
    if (n > to) {
        for (let i = n; i > to; i--) {
            updatedJson[i + 1] = updatedJson[i];
            console.log('In loop');
            console.log(updatedJson);
        }
        updatedJson[to] = item;
    }
    if (n < to) {
        for (let i = n; i < to; i++) {
            updatedJson[i - 1] = updatedJson[i];
            console.log('In loop');
            console.log(updatedJson);
        }
        updatedJson[to] = item;
    }
    console.log('End result');
    console.log(updatedJson);
    setWindowJson(updatedJson);
}
```

In your React code, updatedJson is a new array, but the objects it contains are still references to the same objects as WindowJson.

When you modify updatedJson by splicing, you're also affecting the original objects in WindowJson because they share the same references.